# Office 365 - language in the downloaded software

Tags: language, office365

My company is about to buy Office 365 Small business premium, i.e. the variant where you can download the software to your laptop. My question is: **When the software (e.g. Excel) is downloaded and installed, where is the language (e.g. swedish, english) decided**?

We work in a multilanguage environment and would like to have the language on the clients decided on case by case basis. At the "365" site, we will stay with english.

Given the newness of Office 365 Small business premium, this is a question that Microsoft currently can't give a definite answer to.

Comment: New or old, Microsoft developed it so I can't see why they would be unable to answer your queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there was no answer from Microsoft, I will add an answer that I received from a former colleague that has access to Office 365 and information from Dustin.

The language of the client is decided at download from the site, see below.

[image: O365 language selection]

Once the client is downloaded, the language is fixed and it can only be changed through downloading the client again.

Comment: I don't think it is fixed. You should contact MS Support for this.